# Hosting the same instance of a control in different windows in wpf using ContentPresenter

Tags: wpf, windows, instance, contentpresenter, frameworkelement

- I have three windows - Main, sub1 and sub2.
- A class called Context (which is my model).
- The context has a property of type *FrameworkElement* and is instantiated in Main.
- From Main, I am instantiating sub1 and sub2.
- sub1's data context is set to Main's Context.
- sub2's data context is also set to Main's Context.
- sub1 and sub2 has similar xaml. The xaml just hosts the *FrameworkElement* of the Context in a **ContentPresenter**.
- When I run the application, the *FrameworkElement* is hosted only in sub2.

I know its not possible to host the same instance in both the places, still, is there a way to detach and attach the content when sub1 and sub2 are activated?